# Restrict access to AWS API endpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have a lambda function which is accessible via the AWS API, I have got a link from the API which if hit will call the Lambda function, how do I restrict the access to this link such that it's not accessible to public?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AWS API Gateway provides a way to restrict access to the resources.

You just need to enable it in API Gateway Console.

Click on the resource method -> Method Request -> Settings -> Authorization
And select `AWS_IAM`

Then you can access the API with access key and secret key only.

[AWS Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/permissions.html) for your reference.

Screenshots for your reference

[image: Method Request]

[image: Settings]